# Is $a\sim b$ exactly when $a \times b$ is divisible by $3$ an equivalence relation?

Tags: relations

Let $\sim$ be define so that $a\sim b$ exactly when $a \times b$ is divisible by $3$. Is this an equivalence relation? If not, which of the three properties (reflexive, symmetric, transitive) does not hold?

Solution:

We need to test each of the following cases to see if they hold.

Here are my assumptions:
$a\times b$ is divisible by $3$ in the following cases:

- Case 1: $3\mid a $, and $3\nmid b$. Example: $a=3, b=2, a\times b=6$
- Case 2: $3\nmid {a}$, and $3\mid b$. Example: $a=2, b=3, a\times b=6$
- Case 3: $3\mid a$, and $3\mid b$. Example: $a=3, b=3, a\times b=9$

**Reflexive Test:**

- $aRa: = \{(a,a): 3\mid a\times a\}$
- $bRb: = \{(b,b): 3\mid b\times b\}$

This fails in $aRa$ when $a$ is not divisible by $3$ according to *case 1*.
This also fails in $bRb$ when $b$ is not divisible by $3$ according to *case 2*.

**Symmetric Test:**

- $aRb: = \{(a,b): 3\mid a\times b\}$
- $bRa: = \{(b,a): 3\mid b\times a\}$

This works because if $a\times b$ is divisible by $3$, then $a$ is divisible by $a\times b$ and $b$ is divisible by $b\times a$.

**Transitive Test:** Honestly I am not exactly sure how to describe the relation here, since we need $a$, $b$ and $c$.

What is $c$ in this case, is it the result of $a\times b$?

Am I on the right track?

Comment: $aRa$ is false if $3$ doesn't divide $a$.

Comment: Strictly speaking, this question isn't well-posed - you need to specify a *domain* for the relation. Presumably the domain is the natural numbers, but this matters: if we take for instance the domain to be $\{3\}$, then the relation *is* an equivalence relation.

Comment: Well, this question comes from a book word-for-word. I did not modify it, for me is self-study. If the question is out of the this sites scope, I do not mind removing it.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: You said a very well point. Indeed, what I was thinking about it is that point.

Comment: @lucidgold This question is *definitely* appropriate for this site, and I didn't mean my comment as a criticism of you, just the question. I hope I don't come off as overly critical. I think my main advice is, go a bit more slowly, and think about what the definitions of "reflexive", "symmetric", "transitive"  actually mean, before trying to solve the problem right off the bat. EDIT: Oh, I see, I wrote "you need to . . ." - I meant the abstract 'you' there :P, i.e., "**one** needs to . . ."

Comment: Understood. The book has many vague moments, and it doesn’t have a great rating (2.5) on amazon: http://www.amazon.com/Discrete-Mathematics-Ducks-Sarah-Marie-Belcastro/dp/1466504994

Comment: x is always in relation with 3m and 3m is always in relation with y but xy can be non-divible by 3, so there is not transitivity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're making things more complicated by using notation, rather than thinking about what the question means.

**Reflexivity**. Is it the case that, for every number $a$, $a^2$ is divisible by $3$? If yes, then the relation is reflexive. If no, then the relation is not reflexive.

**Symmetry**. Is it the case that, if $ab$ is divisible by $3$, then $ba$ is divisible by $3$? If yes, then the relation is symmetric. If no, then the relation is not symmetric.

**Transitivity**. Is it the case that, if $ab$ is divisible by $3$ and $bc$ is divisible by $3$, then $ac$ is divisible by $3$? If yes, then the relation is transitive. If no, then the relation is not transitive.

Do you see the answers to these questions?

---

Note that these questions are just translations, into words, of the usual formal definition. E.g., $R$ is reflexive iff for every $a$, we have $aRa$. In this case, "$xRy$" means "$xy$ is divisible by $3$," so the question "Is $R$ reflexive?" is the same as the question "Is it the case that, for every $a$, $a^2$ is divisible by $3$?"

Comment: How do I "modify" the original relation to include $c$ so I can test for the Transitivity case? How does $c$ fit?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "modify the original relation to include $c$". To test if $R$ is transitive, you ask, "Is it the case that - for any $a, b, c$ - if $aRb$ and $bRc$, then $aRc$?" I think you're trying to jump straight to an algorithm for solving this type of problem, without thinking about what it means for long enough.

Answer (score 0):

$3$ is prime, so $a\sim b \iff 3|ab \iff 3|a \text{ or } 3|b$.

$\sim$ is not transitive: $1\sim 3$ and $3\sim 1$, but not $1\sim 1$.

As just seen, $\sim$ is not reflexive.

It is symmetric, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

It is not transitive! Take $3|(2\times 3),~~3|(3\times 4)$ but $3$ does not divide $2\times 4$.

Comment: In fact, this shows that the relation is *connected* in a strong way - for *any* $a$ and $c$, there is some $b$ such that $aRb$ and $bRc$ (specifically, any $b$ which is divisible by $3$).

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Yes that's right.